# How to find the neighbors of a vertex on an arbitrary mesh?

Tags: c#, c++

https://i.stack.imgur.com/30nLa.png

I have an arbitrary mesh like the one in the picture in the above link (it's just an example, but I need this to work on any mesh; numbers are just there for reference, I cannot rely on vertex ordering).

Cycling through all the vertices (let's say starting from the vertex marked in red) I need to find the four neighbor vertices marked in blue.

I have the following data:

- Triangles array (vertices and edges)
- Vertices array (positions in space)
- Edges array (pair of vertices)

I tried cycling through the Triangles array and pick the ones that share the starting vertex, ending up with something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6Fqa.png

How can I filter the data further to end up with only the four vertices marked in blue?

Comment: Why is vertex #37 and vertex #0 not a neighbor vertex?

Comment: They are, but I don't need them, I just need 36, 3, 1 and 35

Comment: Then how do you know which vertices to exclude?

Comment: That's the question. Let's say the meshes will always be some tubular shapes like that one. Also, I can guarantee that all triangles orientation will be like that (though I can't guarantee vertices ordering). So basically I need the "cross" defined by those 5 points (1, 2, 36, 3, 35).

Comment: How do you know there will be a "cross" ? What defines a "cross" ?

Comment: You're right, I think I need to give some more context. Let's say I have this mesh in a game, and I want the character to onlye be able to move on straigh lines (i.e., no diagonals). So my idea was to create some sort of linking from each vertex to it's allowed neighbors, if it makes sense.

Comment: I know there will always be a "cross" because I will create the meshes myself, so I will use the same criteria for every mesh.

Comment: If you create the mesh yourself, you should be able to extract the information when you create the mesh?

Comment: In a sense, yes. But since there could be quite a few vertices, I wanted to find a more automatic solution.

Comment: Maybe for each vertex define four preferred directions. E.g. D1 =(d1x,d1y,d1z), D2=(d2x,d2y,d2x),..., then for the six candidate vertices, calculate the one which has the smallest deviation from D1, select this vertex, then calculate which of the remaining five has the smallest deviation from D2, select this vertex, ... and so on. The deviation could be measured as the smallest angle or smallest distance for a normalized direction..

Answer (score 2):

I solved it in two steps: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHyyW.png

1) select all triangles sharing the starting vertex

2) filter out edges that fall in this criteria:

- longest edge in a triangle (i.e., hypotenuse)
- does not contain starting vertex